# SVG - How do I cut a <path> in half?

Tags: javascript, svg, drawing

I need to cut an existing path (curve) at a specific point in javascript. For example, if I have the following path:

```
<path stroke-width="3"
      stroke="black"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
      id="line_test"
      d="M125,165 C125,165 125,164 125,164">
</path>
```

From that, I could get the midpoint like so:

```
var line = document.getElementById("line_test");
var length = line.getTotalLength();
var midpoint = line.getPointAtLength(length/2);
```

Once I get that midpoint, I want to remove the rest of the path completely. Is there a function that will allow me to get a subpath? A drawing library isn't really an option for me.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question - and would it work 5+ years on ? Interested to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called [getPathSegAtLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPathSegAtLength) (available on path elements) and it returns an index into the [pathSegList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGAnimatedPathData__pathSegList), that index can e.g be used to slice the pathSegList there.

The [pathSegList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegList) is an array-like list, and if you use some of the very latest browsers you can use normal array notation to step through the list, but it's more compatible to use the interface defined in SVG 1.1 right now.

Comment: This no longer works, as `getPathSegAtLength` was removed in SVG 2

Comment: Any idea how I can use this version of SVG (1.1) and access these methods? I have the same problem here to cut paths in half and output a new path from it, seems impossible programatically...